# Can we simply set expiry field to true instead of setting timeout in redis

Tags: redis

I am configuring volatile-LRU eviction policy in redis because I want to expire only few keys, so it is going to expire only the keys where expiration timeout has been set, But I don't want to set expiration timeout instead I want to set expiration field to true, so that those keys will be availble for volatile-lru policy to expire once memory is full.

Can I set expiration field to simply "true" instead of setting timeout?

Comment: NO, you cannot.

Comment: Can you not set expiry to a very large number?